# Dependency-Track is forgetting suppressions on vulnerabilities

Tags: owasp, owasp-dependency-track

I included dependency track in my build-pipeline with:

`mvn cyclonedx:makeAggregateBom dependency-track:upload-bom`

My maven project is configured like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.github.pmckeown</groupId>
    <artifactId>dependency-track-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <dependencyTrackBaseUrl>https://dependency-track.<my-company.com></dependencyTrackBaseUrl>
        <apiKey>${env.DEPENDENCY_TRACK_API_KEY}</apiKey>
        <failOnError>true</failOnError>
        <pollingConfig>
            <pause>2</pause>
            <attempts>30</attempts>
        </pollingConfig>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This all works fine and I get the analysis results in dependency-track.

Now I suppress some found vulnerabilities in dependency-track, because they do not affect my project.

Some time later (I think not immediately) dependency-track seems to forget some of the suppressions and shows the vulnerabilities again.

This in particular happens with the `spring-security-web:5.7.8` dependency:
[image]

Is there something wrong with how I call dependency-track? Or is it more likely misconfigured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. I use the same tool as you (cdxgen) to generate the SBOM and then pass this SBOM to Dependency Track. In my case, all these steps are jobs in a pipeline which is run frequently. I tried to troubleshoot the issue and this was the scenario that lead to it:

- Pipeline #01: All jobs succeed.
- Pipeline #02: A new vulnerable dependency is introduced, so the pipeline fails. I go to DT (Dependency Track) and supress the vulnerability.
- Pipeline #03: All jobs succeed.
- Pipeline #04: Same vulnerability as in #02.
  After researching, I saw that the cdxgen in #03 was generating an empty SBOM (due a execution fallback) and, obviously, DT had nothing to report, so the pipeline was green. My assumption is that this fact induces DT to forget the supressed vulnerabilities, as the SBOM is empty and there are no dependencies. In the next run (#04), the SBOM is properly generated and DT has lost the supression, that is why it keeps appearing.

I opened [this issue](https://github.com/CycloneDX/cdxgen/issues/485) and looks like it is fixed now, just upgrade to the latest version.